# Kotlin: How to handle function of Any input type and given output type

Tags: kotlin

I have functions with signature `(ShellInput) -> ShellOutput`. Reference to these is stored in a map:

```
mutableMapOf<String, (ShellInput) -> ShellOutput>("trim" to ::trim)
```

These are then fetched from this map and invoked via reflection. Now there's a need to have functions where input type can vary, so I tried:

```
mutableMapOf<String, (Any) -> ShellOutput>("trim" to ::trim)
```

But this does not work. How can I handle this?

Comment: Does `trim` function input type is `Any` and `ShellOutput` as return statement?

Comment: @StanislavBondar Nope. trim remains the same, there would be another function lets say trim-file (FileInput) -> ShellOutput

Comment: Well if these will always be functions and not lambdas you can use `KFunction<ShellOutput>` instead

Comment: @1blustone That's a good point. I'd select it if it were an answer

Comment: heh, it seems I'm too late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, putting `::trim` as a value into a `mutableMapOf<String, (Any) -> ShellOutput>` would break type safety: when you take a value out of the map afterwards, it is typed as `(Any) -> ShellOutput`, letting you to pass `Any` as an argument to the function. The type system does not allow that.

As a workaround you can use a [star-projected](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) type `Function1<*, ShellOutput>`, which means that the argument type is unknown:

```
mutableMapOf<String, Function1<*, ShellOutput>>("trim" to ::trim)
```

When you get a value from this map, you'll see that the argument type the function accepts is `Nothing`. This is totally expected, the type system again preserves type safety: there is nothing you can safely pass to a function with an unknown parameter type (`Nothing` is the type with no values).

Now it's time for you to show the compiler that you know more about the types than it does, by using an unchecked cast:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val trim = functions["trim"] as Function1<ShellInput, ShellOutput>
```

You can encapsulate the cast into an extension, like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> Map<String, Function1<*, ShellOutput>>.getWithParameter(key: String): 
    Function1<T, ShellOutput> = 
    get(key) as Function1<T, ShellOutput>

// Usage:
functions.getWithParameter<ShellInput>("trim")
```

---

Alternatively, use `KFunction<ShellOutput>`. It will save you from unchecked casts, but it is less safe right from the start as it does not control the number of arguments, you can `.call(...)` such function references with any number of arguments of any type.

Comment: While I am aware of the existence of `KFunction1` from the Ctrl+Q shortcut I can never seem to declare a variable of that type, as the type apparently does not exist. I do have `kotlin-reflect` as a dependency.

Comment: You need to import it explicitly, `import kotlin.reflect.KFunction1`, not sure why the IDE hides this type from completion.

Comment: Wow. That's definitely strange. If I click on [the link to it](https://i.imgur.com/kSFjFf9.png) in the documentation window, nothing happens. Additionally, the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/index.html) has no mention of `KFunction1` at all. Thanks!

Comment: I believe, it has something to do with the fact that `KFunctionN` types are somewhat special, this spec document calls them *fictitious*: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md

Comment: Ah, right, I thought that might be the case, they seem to be generated in some way. `import kotlin.reflect.KFunction87567` for example works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updated the answer: seems like `Function1<*, ShellOutput>` is a better option since it does not require that kind of import.